# Discord.js roleUpdate event

Tags: discord, discord.js

What I'm trying to do, is a simple event logger where it will output, say if a role lost/gained a permission. So I thought of comparing the two, and simple subtract them, so it only displays one certain permission. Instead, I get 1 undefined (Permission lost, check code below) and other just goes blank, as in no text at all (Permission gain, check code below). I've already done it, say if a guild member loses a role or gets a role, but it doesn't work the same way.

What have I done wrong, and how can I continue from here?

Code:

```
bot.on("roleUpdate", async (oldRole, newRole) => {


if (oldRole.permissions !== newRole.permissions) {

  if (oldRole.permissions > newRole.permissions) {
    //Permission lost
    let oldPerms = oldRole.serialize()
    let newPerms = newRole.serialize()
    var permLost = Object.keys(oldPerms, newPerms).find(perm => perm[newPerms] - oldPerms)
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(`Role changed permissions`)
    .setColor("#ffc500")
    .setDescription(`**${newRole.toString()} has lost the ${permLost} permission**`)
    .setFooter(`ID: ${newRole.id} `)
    .setTimestamp()
    logchannel.send(embed).catch()

} else if (oldRole.permissions < newRole.permissions) {
    //Permission given
    let oldPerms = oldRole.serialize()
    let newPerms = newRole.serialize()
    var permGained = Object.keys(oldPerms, newPerms).filter(perm => perm[newPerms] - oldPerms)
    const embed2 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(`Role changed permissions`)
    .setColor("#ffc500")
    .setDescription(`**${newRole.toString()} has been given the ${permGained} permission**`)
    .setFooter(`ID: ${newRole.id} `)
    .setTimestamp()
    logchannel.send(embed2).catch()

  }
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some stuff of your code and I think is everything nice.

```js
client.on("roleUpdate", async (oldRole, newRole) => {

    if (oldRole.permissions !== newRole.permissions) {

        const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(`Role changed permissions`)
            .setColor("#ffc500")
            .setFooter(`ID: ${newRole.id} `)
            .setTimestamp()

        const oldPerms = oldRole.serialize();
        const newPerms = newRole.serialize();

        const permUpdated = [];

        for (const [key, element] of Object.entries(oldPerms)) {
            if (newPerms[key] !== element) permUpdated.push(key);
        }

        if (oldRole.permissions > newRole.permissions) {
            //Permission lost

            embed.setDescription(`**${newRole.toString()} has lost the ${permUpdated.join(", ")} permission**`)
            logchannel.send(embed).catch()

        } else if (oldRole.permissions < newRole.permissions) {
            //Permission given

            embed.setDescription(`**${newRole.toString()} has been given the ${permUpdated.join(", ")} permission**`)
            logchannel.send(embed).catch()

        }
    }

});
```

I changed your new Embed... beacause, the only difference between those embeds was the description, so you just need to create one embed and set the description before send.

-------[image: Showing some results]

Comment: I added and removed the permission ADMINISTRADOR which means the same of ALL PERMISSIONS of a role.